# Show a square plot under chunks in Rstudio

Tags: r, plot, markdown

I am programming in Rstudio using markdown files, alternating between Markdown and R chunks of code. If I plot something in a chunk, the plot is shown below the chunk.

Does anybody know how I can make the plot look square instead of rectangular?

Comment: See fig.height and fig.width chunk options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this kind or header of chunk with fig.width = fig.height

```
<<R_chunk_title,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,fig.width=6,fig.height=6,cache=TRUE>>=
```